# Liquibase - SQLite - "Add Column" from a changeset drops table primary constraint

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, liquibase

Maybe I missed something, but when I try to add a new column to an existing table that has a primary key, that primary key was dropped for some reason.

ChangeSet:

```
<changeSet author="author" id="21">
    <addColumn tableName="my_table">
        <column name="new_column_test" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet
```

I used this work around (And works):

```
<changeSet author="author" id="21">
    <sql splitStatements="false">
        ALTER TABLE my_table ADD new_column_test VARCHAR(255);
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

I don't know what's wrong, but it's very odd.

I googled a lot for something that fix this, but no luck.

Thank's if someone can help.

Comment: You might try your test case and instead of running the`update` command, instead use the `updateSql` command. If the SQL generated includes the command to drop the constraint, then the problem is indeed in Liquibase somewhere. If not, then it could be something strange with SQLite instead.

Comment: Thanks, so I ran updateSQL to check the output SQL and there is no Drop command, If this output is the command that will be run in the SQLite, maybe we have something in the SQLite indeed. The strange thing is that if I run the command directly in the SQLite I have no issues with the constraints.

Comment: I did a new test, I ran the result of updateSQL command directly into SQLite and works. I think that something between liquibase and SQLite cause the Drop of the constraint.